# Boiler issue diagnostic steps for a layperson (E37/E99)

Tags: boiler, uk

I'm having some boiler woes which seem to have stumped my landlord's plumber, and I'm wondering if there's any clues people more experienced with this setup may recognise, or any recommended diagnostic steps.

My boiler is a [Keston C32 Combi](http://www.keston.co.uk/assets/pdf/C36%20Combi%20Manual%20WD388-3-2010.pdf), in a London flat. Towards the end of last year, it failed with an "E37" error message (water pressure error). For a long time before this, it had been occasionally showing this error (once every month or two) and I'd been told by the plumber to re-pressure the central heating system to get it working again (which had been working fine). On this occasion it didn't work even when the central heating pressure was above the marked minimum (~1.6 bar).

After an unpleasantly long time with at least 8 visits, the issue was finally resolved and the boiler started working perfectly again (and no-longer required re-pressuring of the central heating). During this time, the following was done:

1. Cleaned heat exchanger
2. Replaced pressuriser
3. Replaced motherboard (old one has visible damage to a component)
4. Replaced a value (sorry; not sure which)
5. Drained system (boiler and central heating)
6. Replaced a fractured part (sorry; not sure which. Quite a small pipework piece, possibly another valve)
7. Replaced some external pipework connecting central heating to boiler
8. Descaled air vent
9. Checked internal thermostat
10. Replaced electrolyte
11. Replaced low-pressure sensor
12. Replaced air vent

After this, it worked fine for several months, and held pressure in the central heating system at about 2.3 bar. So that's the history.

---

Recently (shortly after being tested for gas safety, which it passed), the boiler has shown issues again. Now it is alternating between working and displaying the "E37" error several times each minute, but the central heating pressure is still at 2.3 bar. This makes me think it must be air trapped in the system again, implying the new air vent has failed already. Additionally when there are continued demands for hot water (longer than about 1 minute), it fails with "E99" (communication error) and the water goes cold.

The plumber will be taking another look in a few days, but since this has been such a problematic fault, I'm wondering if there are any diagnostic steps I (as a lay-person) can perform to ensure this doesn't drag on like it did the last time.

Comment: What ended up being the problem? We've got a Keston C36 Combi boiler with the E37 error. Topping up the water pressure via the fill loop results in the exhaust pipe letting water out.

Comment: @Dennis I think the problem turned out to be that the replacement motherboard was the wrong model so it wasn't properly compatible, but it was a while ago and I might be misremembering. If water is coming out of the exhaust pipe then it's a different problem. Do you know what the pressure is? I recall that E37 can be both for low *and high* pressure errors, so maybe your boiler is over-pressure? The main problem with my boiler was certainly that the air vent had failed (so there was air in the system which was not venting). But I don't know how you can test that on yours.